# The polynomial subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a set of 6 polynomials in $\mathbb{R}_5[x]$ over $\mathbb{R}$ field,
assume $sp(A) = \mathbb{R}_5[x]$ which of the following is true?

**1.** It might be that $A$ holds exactly 4 polynomials from second degree.
**2.** It might be that $A$ holds exactly 4 polynomials from first degree.

I think the two argument are equivalent, and in order to span $\mathbb{R}_5[x]$
a set must have $6$ vectors, and since 4 of the vectors are in 2nd or 3rd degree it means there will always be an unreachable vector and thus the groups described in **1.** and **2.** cannot span $\mathbb{R}_5[x]$.

Comment: Can you be more explicit why your argument fails with **3.** It might be that $A$ holds exactly 4 polynomials from third degree?

Comment: The question only mentions first and second degree, I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Consider $F$ the span of the 4 polynomials in the assumptions and $G$ the span of the other two. Then use $6=\dim (F+G)\leq \dim F+\dim G$ to reach a contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short:

$$A:=\,\{x^4\,,\,x^4+1\,,\,x^4+x\,,\,x^4+x^2\,,\,x^3\,,\,x^5\}\;\implies \,\text{Span}(A)=\Bbb R_5[x]$$

and $\,A\,$ contains four quartic polynomials (check the above vectors are line. independent) .

OTOH, if $\,A\,$ contains four linear polynomials then it automatically is a linearly dependent set, since all these four linear pol's are elements of $\;\Bbb R_1[x]\;$ , which is a two-dimensional space, so that $\,\text{Span}(A)\;$ cannot be the whole $\,\Bbb R_5[x]\,$

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is not exact, you claim that there will be unreachable
vectors but you because of the given assumption - but you don't explain
why.

**Hint:** What is the dimensions of $\mathbb{R}_{1}[x],\mathbb{R}_{2}[x]$
?

Recall that if $V$ is of dimension $n$ then any $n+1$ vectors
are lineally dependent.

**Note:** the subset of all polynomials of degree exactly $2$ (or exactly
$1$) is not a vector subspace (since, for example $x^{2}+(-x^{2})=0$
is not in this subset, or $(x^{2}+x)+(-x^{2})$).

Comment: I don't understand why $A$ must be linearly dependent, the standard basis hold $(1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5)$ which are $6$ vectors.

Comment: I say that if we assume that $v_i = \alpha_i + \beta_ix +\gamma_ix^2$ for $1 \leq i \leq 4$ and $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ then there are two more vectors left to be in any degree, assume one is from 3rd and one is from 4th degree, none could get to a 5th degree polynomial by any linear combination.

Comment: @Georgey - First, $A$ need not be linearly dependent. But with any of the assumptions
$1$ or $2$ in the question, I provided with a hint to prove it does
indeed linearly dependent hence can not span $\mathbb{R}_{6}[x]$
(since then the span of $A$ is at most of degree $5$).

Secondly, What if the other vectors are something like $x^{5}+x^{4}-2x^{3}+x^{2}-1$
and $x^{5}-x^{4}+x^{3}+x+1$ ? maybe there is some linear combination
to give each $x^{i}$ that is needed

Comment: $A$ needs to span $\mathbb{R}_5$ and not $\mathbb{R}_6$. I haven't understand your hint, I know that $dim(\mathbb{R}_1) = 1$ and $dim(\mathbb{R}_2) = 2$ but how does it help me to prove the required? If $A$ needs to span $\mathbb{R}_5[x]$ and has 6 vectors, then $A$ has the exact same number of vectors such as the basis of $\mathbb{R}_5[x]$.

Comment: I think it might be easier to prove that if __1.__ or __2.__ exist then $A$ is not a vector subspace.

Comment: @Georgey - $A$ can not be a vector subspace since its cardinalty is $6$. Proving this does not require the assumption $1$ or $2$

Comment: @Georgey - I used the same notation as you - the polynomials over $\mathbb{R}^1$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$ which have dimensions $2,3$ accordingly. hence any subset of $4$ elements are  linearly dependent, then $A$ is  linearly dependent

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8935/discussion-between-georgey-and-belgi)